# Select unique combinations (unique on both sides)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**EDIT**: added a link to Fiddle for a more comprehensive sample (actual dataset)

---

I wonder if the below is possible in `SQL`, in `BigQuery` in particular, and in one `SELECT` statement.

Consider following input:

```
  Key | Value 
 -----|------- 
  a   |     2 
  a   |     3 
  b   |     2 
  b   |     3 
  b   |     5 
  c   |     2
  c   |     5 
  c   |     7
```

Logic: select the lowest value "available" for each key. Available meaning not yet assigned/used. See below.

```
  Key | Value |                    Rule                    
 -----|-------|-------------------------------------------- 
  a   |     2 | keep                                       
  a   |     3 | ignore because key "a" has a value already 
  b   |     2 | ignore because value "2" was already used  
  b   |     3 | keep                                       
  b   |     5 | ignore because key "b" has a value already 
  c   |     2 | ignore because value "2" was already used  
  c   |     5 | keep                                       
  c   |     7 | ignore because key "c" has a value already
```

Hence expected outcome:

```
  Key | Value 
 -----|------- 
  a   |     2 
  b   |     3 
  c   |     5
```

Here the SQL to create the dummy table:

```
with t as ( select 
'a' key, 2 value UNION ALL select 'a', 3 
UNION ALL select 'b', 2 UNION ALL select 'b', 3 UNION ALL select 'b', 5
UNION ALL select 'c', 2 UNION ALL select 'c', 5 UNION ALL select 'c', 7 
)
select * from t
```

**EDIT**: here another [dataset](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/34343/0)

Not sure what combination of `FULL JOIN`, `DISTINCT`, `ARRAY` or `WINDOW` functions I can use.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: i have deleted my answer for now till will fix it. sorry for this

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: This is an incorrect answer that worked with the original example dataset, but has issues (as seen with comprehensive sample). I'm leaving it here for now to maintain comment history.

---

I don't have a specific `BigQuery` answer, but here is one `SQL` solution using a [Common Table Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) and recursion.

```
WITH MyCTE AS 
(
  /* ANCHOR SUBQUERY */
  SELECT MyKey, MyValue 
  FROM MyTable t
  WHERE t.MyKey = (SELECT MIN(MyKey) FROM MyTable)

  UNION ALL

  /* RECURSIVE SUBQUERY */
  SELECT t.MyKey, t.MyValue
  FROM MyTable t
  INNER JOIN MyCTE c 
     ON c.MyKey < t.MyKey
    AND c.MyValue < t.MyValue
)

SELECT MyKey, MIN(MyValue)
FROM MyCTE 
GROUP BY MyKey
;
```

Results:

```
  Key | Value 
 -----|------- 
  a   |     2 
  b   |     3 
  c   |     5
```

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/80b6b/15)

Comment: Thanks for trying but it doesn't get to the expected outcome. Your first `MIN()` excludes upfront `(b,3)` and `(c,5)`

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated my answer with an example that returns the expected results.

Comment: I believe indeed recursion is necessary but `BigQuery` does not support `WITH RECURSIVE`. Using your code, I ran another sample here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/34337/0 but some keys are gone like `068`.
The algorithm is actually more complicated than I thought and is easier done programmatically (py/pandas) vs. non-atomic SQL.